# Efficient way of removing similar arrays in an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to analyze some documents and find similarities in them. After analysis, I have an array, the elements of which are arrays of data from documents considered similar. But sometimes I have two almost similar elements, and naturally I want to leave the biggest of them. For simplification:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,5,6]...]
```

How do I efficiently process the data that I get:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10]...]
```

I suppose I could intersect every array, and if the intersected array matches one of the original arrays - I ignore it. Here is a quick code I wrote:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10], [1,2,3,5,6], [7,9,10]]
cleaned = []

data.each_index do |i|
  similar = false
  data.each_index do |j|
    if i == j
      next
    elsif data[i]&data[j] == data[i]
      similar = true
      break
    end
  end
  unless similar
    cleaned << data[i]
  end
end

puts cleaned.inspect
```

Is this an efficient way to go? Also, the current behaviour only allows to leave out arrays that are a few elements short, and I might want to merge similar arrays if they occur:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [1,3,4,5,6]] => [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

Comment: The last part of your question requires you to define "similar enough to merge"  - for example how many elements (or what ratio of them) need to match before you want to merge?

Comment: @NeilSlater, It haven't thought about it yet and haven't analysed much data to see how often this happens. From one batch of documents I noticed two similar arrays of data, which differed by one element ( [same_stuff, x], [same_stuff, y]. I suppose the difference might be slightly bigger.

Comment: -1 The question is not well defined.

Comment: @sawa what exactly is not well defined? You can ask for clarification if I explained something that is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete any element in the list if it is fully contained in another element:

```
data.delete_if do |arr|
  data.any? { |a2| !a2.equal?(arr) && arr - a2 == [] }
end
# => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

This is a bit more efficient than your suggestion since once you decide that an element should be removed, you don't check against it in the next iterations.

Comment: Great, this is indeed more efficient. When I want to merge some of the elements, I will have to resort to something else, I guess.

Comment: This will fail to remove duplicate arrays.

Comment: That only partly helps.

Comment: @sawa, actually, I removed the `uniq!`, as it will affect the performance. I replaced `!=` with `!.equal?` instead. This will remove duplicates _and_ have better performance than `!=`

Comment: With your previous solution using `uniq!`, you were able to remove exact duplicates but not the arrays that have the same elements but in different order. Your solution with `equal?` will fully work. But you should have tried harder to think by yourself before asking me.

Comment: @sawa - you are wrong! `uniq!` removes exact duplicates, and `arr - a2 == []` removes arrays with same elements in different order. I believe it is you who didn't try hard enough - having thought of that weakness, you could have at least _tried_ your theory (by running the code)...